# equivalent definition for Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove that if $\lim_{k \to \infty} \| x_{k+p}-x_k\|=0$ for all $p \in \mathbb{N}$ then $x_k$ is a Cauchy sequence $\in \mathbb{R}^n$? This result seems to be quite intuitive but I'm having difficulty to find a natural constant where $\|x_q-x_c\|< \epsilon$ for all $q$ and $c$ larger than that constant.  ($\|\ \|$ is a euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is false... Take $x_k=\log(k)$, it has your property but is not a Cauchy sequence...

If you want to have a Cauchy sequence, you should better use a property like $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \limits\sup_{k\geq n} u_k =0$