# $\text { Prove } u_{n}=\frac{\cos 5}{5}+\frac{\cos 5^{2}}{5^{2}}+\cdots+\frac{\cos 5^{n}}{5^{n}} \text { is convergent in } \mathbb{R} \text {. } $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

The way the book proved it is this:

Its idea was to prove that the sequence is Cauchy then it follows that it is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$ ;
[image]

But my way that I want to check if it's right or wrong is :

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|U_{n+p}-U_{n}\right| &=\left|\frac{\cos 5^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}}+\frac{\cos 5^{n+2}}{5^{n+2}}+\cdots+\frac{\cos 5^{n+p}}{5^{n+p}}\right| \\
& \leq\left|\frac{\cos 5^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}}\right|+\left|\frac{\cos 5^{n+2}}{5^{n+2}}\right|+\cdots+\left|\frac{\cos 5^{n+p}}{5^{n+p}}\right| \\
& \leq\left|\frac{1}{5^{n+1}}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{5^{n+2}}\right|+\cdots+\left|\frac{1}{5^{n+p}}\right|=\frac{1}{5^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{5^{n+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{5^{n+p}} \\
&=\frac{1}{5^{n+1}} \frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{p}}{1-\frac{1}{5}}=\frac{1}{5^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{5}{4} \cdot\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{p}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Then I'll take the limit of $|U_{n+p}-U_{n}|$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, which it's zero ; so isn't that enough to prove that the sequence is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: That is *not* sufficient, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1536274/42969 and the linked questions.

Comment: The series $\sum \frac {cos (5^{n})} {5^{n}}$ is absolutely  convergent by M-test since $|\cos x| \leq 1$.

Comment: Put $a_n=\ln n$. Then $|a_{n+p}-a_n|=|\ln(n+p)-\ln(n)|=|\ln(1+\frac{p}{n})|\to\ln 1=0$ when $n\to\infty$ - yet $(a_n)$ is a divergent sequence. The difference between what you want to use and what you actually need to use for Cauchy criterion is similar to the difference between pointwise and uniform convergence: it is not enough that $|a_{n+p}-a_n|$ becomes arbitrarily small with $n$ big enough, but also that the "moment" when that happens is *independent on $p$*.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2747971/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2741224/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1436100/42969

Comment: thanks folks all makes sense now